# Trouble Determining End Game

Tags: java, android

I am trying to check to see if a player can no longer make moves but i cant seem to figure out how to check for it.
Say i have 5 tiles or less and each tile has a value between 1 and 3 on it. I want to run through the tiles and check if there are any possible combinations that will add up to 10.  Its not as simple as just checking the total because there could be 3 tile with 3's on them and one with a 2.  I have spent hours trying to figure this out....

Any ideas on how i could check for all possible combinations? I only need to see if one combination is possible. As soon as one is found i would break the loop to reduce the number of checks.

Edit:  If it helps you can kinda see what im talking about if you download it. Its Numero: 21 on the android.

The object of the game is to add tiles to 21.  So when the user gets down to a few tiles, sometimes a combination of 21 cant be acheived even when the total of all the tiles is above 21 because the numbers dont add up to exactly 21.  This creates a problem because i am unable to check for that and tell the user that they have lost.

I really dont even know where to begin when it comes to checking for it. i can loop through all the tiles multiple times but the thhing is a combination could be as many tiles are on the board. So i have to check for combinations of 3, then 4 , then 5 and so on until the number of tiles left is reached.  Its kind of hard for me to explain this exactly

#### Corrective Edit For Future Reference:

I apologize for my initial question for being so ambiguous.  Happened to be the first question I ever asked on here...  This is a much better description of the problem and the solution.  I decided to keep the previous text for record.

The game has numerous numbered tile and I you have to add them up to 21 to remove.  You can not go over 21. It has to be exact.

What I was wanting to check is if there was still a combination of tiles that could be used to add up to 21 exactly.  A basic sum check doesn't work because you could have 5 number 5 tiles and be more than 21 but not possible to eliminate anymore.

### Solution

As @mellamokb answered subset sum recursion needed to be used.  Basically you loop through the tiles and on each tile you call the same function twice.  One call adds the current tile and the other continues to the next iteration without adding the current tile.  If any return true then the function is true.  Basically a binary tree.

Code

```
boolean validate(tiles, index, subtotal, total){
    if index >= tiles.length return false;
    if subtotal == total return true;
    return validate(tiles, index + 1, subtotal + tiles[index].number, total) || 
       validate(tiles, index + 1, subtotal, total);
}
```

Call it with

```
validate(tiles, 0, 0, 21)
```

That about does it.

Comment: We need **way** more information to help you...

Comment: First of all what game are you trying to implement and what are the rules for the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a variation of the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  The simplest algorithm is O(2^n), iterating over every possible subset combination by using bit flags, for example.

```
for i = 0 to 2^n - 1
    set subtotal = 0
    for each bit in i
        if bit i is set, add ith element to subtotal
    check subtotal against desired total (i.e., 10)
```

Or, alternatively using recursion:

```
validate(set, index, subtotal, total)
    if index >= set.length return false;
    if subtotal == total return true;
    return validate(set, index + 1, subtotal + set[index], total) || 
           validate(set, index + 1, subtotal, total);
```

Usage:

```
validate(set, 0, 0, 10);
```

Comment: @Shane make sure to mark the answer as correct then